# Link multiple authentication providers for phone and email

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase so please be patient with my question following:

User are able login to my apps using phone authentication or email, but it will generate two different UID for a same user, what I wish to achieve is one user with one UID can login with email or login by phone number (**Merge the phone number and the email in authentication**). May I possible to achieve this at Firebase?

thank you

[image: Problem of one user with two user UID]

Comment: As far I know you can not generate/merge two UID for same user. UID will be unique for every new authentication. Even if the user deletes the app and re-login with same credentials then his old UID will be activated to his account.

Comment: ok, do you have any way or alternative to handle this kind of situation? how can I do for link the same user data in database with two different UID ?

Comment: There is another one method . You can read the documentation here about linking multiple authentication [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking)

Comment: @MohammedFarhan Yes, I read this but I not sure about for the parameter:

`AuthCredential phoneCredential;
phoneCredential=PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(String verificationId, String smsCode);  `

the smsCode is 6 digits number sent from Firebase right??
How about the **verificationId**, where can I get from ?

Comment: Sorry I was away. Thanks for using my suggestions. Cheers @Thomas Law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Finally it works!!]

Finally, I get the expected result, thank you Mohammed Farhan stay along with me.

My previous mistake is send the sms code to firebase before do link multiple auth providers, should call the function below directly after get the sms code from Firebase, everything is nice as expected!!

```
private void linkUserAuth(){
            phoneCredential=PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID,verificationCode);
        firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(phoneCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG,"linkWithCredential:success");
                    FirebaseUser mergeAuthUser=task.getResult().getUser();                 
                }else{
                    Log.w(TAG,"linkWithCredential:failure",task.getException());
                     }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: as far as I know, it is not allowed to save user credentials (like email) in firebase. That is breaking google rules and might result in ban of your app and terminating your dev account...I would be extremely careful with this.