# Why I am not able to link Multiple Auth Providers to an Firebase Account on Android Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have sign in project in jetpack project so, I want to use phone authentication also in my project, so when I complete my process, in firebase providers section, my email and phone number not link, I read [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45917407/18980132) question, and I added this line of code in my project

```
  val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationOtp, otp)
  auth.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential)
  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
```

but still it is not work, any idea?

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(

    private val auth: FirebaseAuth

    ) : ViewModel() {

    lateinit var otp: String

    var verificationOtp = ""
    var popNotification = mutableStateOf<Event<String>?>(null)

    private lateinit var baseBuilder: PhoneAuthOptions.Builder

    fun setActivity(activity: Activity) {
        baseBuilder = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth).setActivity(activity)
    }

    lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken

    fun send(mobileNum: String) {

        val options = baseBuilder
            .setPhoneNumber(mobileNum)
            .setTimeout(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setCallbacks(object :
                PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Completed")

                }

                override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
                    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Failed")

                }

                override fun onCodeSent(otp: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(otp, p1)
                    verificationOtp = otp
                    handledException(customMessage = "Otp Send Successfully")

                }

            })
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }


    fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(otp: String) {
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationOtp, otp)
        auth.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential)
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Successful")

                } else {
                    handledException(customMessage =  "Wrong Otp")

                }
            }
    }


    private fun handledException(exception: Exception? = null, customMessage: String = "") {
        exception?.printStackTrace()
        val errorMsg = exception?.message ?: ""
        val message = if (customMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMsg
        } else {
      

  "$customMessage: $errorMsg"
    }
    popNotification.value = Event(message)
}


}
```

Comment: "still it is not work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo, in firebase for providers section I want to link phone number and email, above code sometimes link them, but sometimes not, why?